# Do fewer support vectors imply a simpler model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, model

I am applying $\epsilon$- and $\nu$-regression to sample data, and I discovered I had different results in terms of the count of support vectors.

When I have fewer support vectors, does it mean that the model is simpler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically your statement is correct.

The number of support vectors depends on how much margin you allow, and the complexity of our model. Every time whey you are trying to twist or rotate the decision curve (or just translation/rotation with linear kernel), one or more support vectors are defined and included. If your data in the input space (or the transformed space with kernel) is linear separable and the patterns are very clear, you may only need very few support vectors, which also indicates your model is simple.

Yet in most cases the patterns are not so evident, so you are actually balance between a high complexity model (tend to overfitting) and a simple model with larger margin (tend to underfitting and misclassify some training data). Such a trade-off is reflected by a change of support vectors number.

Comment: "*Every time whey you are trying to twist or rotate the decision curve, one or more support vectors are defined and included.*" may be a little misleading. In the linear kernel, for example, the shape of the decision boundary is always a hyperplane in input space, regardless of the amount of support vectors.

Comment: @MarcClaesen Thank you Marc. For the hyperplane, perhaps rotation and displacement (translation) are involved, and no twist

Comment: yes, I think that is better!